# angularjs ng-Animate not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

i use angularjs module ngAnimate but this does'nt work why  i use the same reference for angularjs.org

```
<html>
 <head>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
         <link rel="style" href="css/style.css">
         <script src="js/app.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body ng-app="app">
          <div class="content" ng-controller="PrintCtrl">
              <h4>{{title}}</h4>
              <p>it's sample content welcome admin in your website</p>
          </div>
 </body>
```

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('PrintCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
      $scope.title = "The title";
}]);
```

Comment: css is .content.ng-enter {
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:0;
}

/* The finishing CSS styles for the enter animation */
.content.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}

Comment: Did you check your developer console for errors?

Comment: no any error in console ?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your css tag is linked with rel="style". It should be stylesheet instead of style. If your css is working fine, I think the animate should work

Comment: i change to stylesheet with the same problem ?

Comment: could i have a look at ur css file? Did you include the animate css?